# What is $x^{\log n}$ if $x \in \Bbb R^{-}$?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, exponentiation

Suppose $x$ is a negative real number then what is $x^{\log n}$?

Does it exist at all? I have searched for it in wikipedia and got an article there regarding the exponentiation of positive real base but couldn't find any fact regarding exponentiation of the negative real base. That's why I am posting this question here for further clarification l; To know explicitly as to why such kind of exponentiation is not valid.

Any relevant suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you all to those who will spend their your valuable time in reading this question and make an informative and thorough reply to this question.

Comment: You may want to give a read to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases).

Comment: This is the article I am referring here. In this article I didn't get any fact of irrational exponentiation of the negative real base. Is it possible @Sangchul Lee? Let me add a funny comment. Please don't mind. In our bengali accent your name appears to me as শাঁকচুন্নি  which means a witch.

Comment: This requires a bit of knowledge on complex logarithm, but accepting this notion, we simply have $$ w^z := e^{z \log w}. $$ The issue here is that, unlike for the logarithm of positive reals, there is no canonical choice of complex logarithm that 'behaves naturally' on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. So we need some artificial choice of complex logarithm and correspondingly for the complex exponentiation. As an example, using the principal complex logarithm, we have $$(-1)^x = e^{x \log(-1)} = e^{i\pi x} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x). $$

Comment: Is $0^x \neq 0$ for all real $x>0$?

Comment: In many cases, we indeed define $0^x := 0$ for $x > 0$. This choice is natural in view of the continuity of exponentiation $(x, y) \mapsto x^y$.